# Websites tag is worthless, should we kill it?

Tags: discussion, tags

[websites](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/websites) doesn't really mean anything. Should we get rid of it?

Comment: If it wasn't you who asked this question & posted answers, Jorge (with your 20k reputation), I  would consider these 'vote Yes or No' answers as an exemplary case of **rep whoring** ;-)

Comment: Rep on meta.au is about as useful as the websites tag!

Comment: 89 questions about it.

Answer (score 11):

#### Yes

meta tags are bad! This tag doesn't describe anything to do with the questions.

Comment: I think this would be the only questions that would use that tag, http://askubuntu.com/questions/45753/accessing-ie-only-sites , even then the "browser" tag is better for describing it, and for coding we would use the "html" or "css" tags, so that leaves recommending websites, which most would be off topic.

Answer (score -4):

#### No

I like to organize questions about "this website doesn't work" into one spot.